# Get the complete path, including the pound sign (#) in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a server based on Node.js, using Express.

Use case:
A user should be able to retreive his personal content from the server by making an HTTP GET with the following URL: `http://192.168.1.88:3000/content/[userID]`

I have defined a route like this:

```
app.get('/content/:userID', content.MyHandler);
```

In "MyHandler" I am able to read the **userID** and return the appropriate data to the user.

The problem is that when "**userID**" contains a pound sign (#), I only get what is before the # in MyHandler, an consequently I am unable to find who is the user.

So if the **userID** is "123456", everything is fine. But if the **userID** is "1234#567", I get only "1234" in MyHandler.

MyHandler looks like this:

```
exports.MyHandler = function(req, res){
  ...
  var pathChunk = req.url.split("/");
  // sys.puts("--> Path in chunks: " + sys.inspect(pathChunk));
  // Nothing after # sign
  var userID = pathChunk[2];  // Will be incomplete if contains #
};
```

Is there a way to retreive the full **userID** value in MyHandler, regardless of the pound (#) sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL Encode the userID to encode the string in a format that can be passed on the URL line.

This, in javascript would be something like:

```
var userId_encoded = encodeURIComponent(userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't send the hash and everything after to the server.